# Slow LACIE backup for time machine? Is normal?

Tags: mac, backup

I just got a 4tb lacie external drive, i got it connected through usb-c, but it seems too slow compared to my 2tb WD Elements.

It has transfered 200gb in almost 7hours. Is this normal?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems a bit slow, but we don't have enough detail to really know where the bottleneck might be. Wait until Time Machine has finished, then run Blackmagic Disk Speed Test [freeware, on the App Store] to test the relative raw speeds of each device. Note that Time Machine runs at low priority so as to not interfere with your other work, so it will never reach the theoretical maximum Blackmagic tells you.

Comment: Also remember that lots of small files will be slower than one big one.

Comment: Thanks for the replies :) Maybe it's the first backup. Anyways, i'm in no rush. Thanks again!